# Win 7 + VHDL + exuberant Ctags + gVim

Tags: windows, vim, vhdl, ctags

I can not compile ctags(don't have borland builder and mVS) so I use a binary included in zip file. The problem is that it does not recognize 'processes' and in my tags list there are not 'processes' from .vhd file. I've heard that you can fix it by changing the .ctags configuration file but I don't know where the file is on windows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ctag 5.8 help file :

```
FILES
  /ctags.cnf (on MSDOS, MSWindows only) 
  /etc/ctags.conf 
  /usr/local/etc/ctags.conf 
  $HOME/.ctags 
  $HOME/ctags.cnf (on MSDOS, MSWindows only) 
  .ctags 
  ctags.cnf (on MSDOS, MSWindows only)

If any of these configuration files exist, each will be expected to contain
a set of default options which are read in the order listed when ctags starts,
but before the CTAGS environment variable is read or any command line options
are read. (...)
```

So creating a `ctags.conf` in your `C:/users/USER/` directory should work.

You can run `ctags --list-languages` to display the list of all supported languages and check that `VHDL` is indeed in the list.

Comment: In fact ctags.cnf helped me. I've used ctags.cnf with this code inside 

`--langdef=vhdl
--langmap=vhdl:.vhd
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*entity[ \t]+([^ ]+) is/\1/e,entities/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*([^ \t:]+)[ \t]*:[ \t]*process[ \t]*\(/\1/p,processes/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*function[ \t]+([a-z0-9_]+)/\1/f,functions/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*procedure[ \t]+([a-z0-9_]+)/\1/r,procedures/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*type[ \t]+([^ ]+) is/\1/t,type declarations/i`